# Execute two sequences of AsyncTasks serially

Tags: android, android-asynctask

There are 2 sequences of AsyncTasks:

1. `A -> B -> C`
2. `D -> E -> F`

That is in `onPostExecute`, task `A` starts task `B`, which in `onPostExecute` starts task `C`. The same goes for the second sequence.

If the sequences are started like this:

```
    new A().execute();

    // at a later time, but while A is still executing
    new D().execute();
```

Are there and what are the ways to ensure task `D` not started until task `C` has finished?

Comment: is it not okay to call D().execute in onPostExecute() of C ?

Comment: updated the question. D can be started based on some event, while A (or B or C) is being executed.

Comment: what is that event ? How it will be notified ? A, B or C will notify that ?. Please add in more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple queue will work for now:

```
public class OperationsQueue {

    private Operation ongoingOperation;
    private Queue<Operation> queue = new LinkedList<>();

    public void execute(Operation operation) {
        if (ongoingOperation != null)
            queue.add(operation);
        else {
            ongoingOperation = operation;
            operation.setOnFinishedCallback(() -> operationFinished(operation));
            operation.execute();
        }
    }

    private void operationFinished(Operation operation) {
        ongoingOperation = null;
        Operation nextOperation = queue.poll();
        if (nextOperation != null)
            execute(nextOperation);
    }
}

public abstract class Operation {
    protected Runnable onFinished = () -> { };

    public abstract void execute();

    public void setOnFinishedCallback(Runnable onFinished) {
        this.onFinished = onFinished;
    }
}
```

Concrete implementations of `Operation` need to start the first async task in the sequence and the last async task must call onFinished.

That is in case of this sequence:

```
A -> B
```

An operation passes a callback to async task `A` which it passes to async tasks it starts so that the last task `B` calls it in its `onPostExecute`:

```
class SomeOperation extends Operation {
  public void execute() {
    new A(() -> onFinished()).execute();
  } 
}

class A extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
   //...

  public Runnable onSuccess;

   public A(Runnable onSuccess) {
      this.onSuccess = onSuccess; 
  }

   onPostExecute() {
      new B(onSuccess).execute();
   }
}

class B extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
   //...

  public Runnable onSuccess;

   public B(Runnable onSuccess) {
      this.onSuccess = onSuccess; 
  }

   onPostExecute() {
      onSuccess.run();
   }
}
```

`SomeOperation` and its underlying tasks may now be executed serially:

```
OperationsQueue queue = new OperationsQueue();
queue.execute(new SomeOperation());
queue.execute(new SomeOperation());
```

Task `A` of the second `SomeOperation` will not execute until task `B` on the first finishes.

Answer (score 1):

There is a framework that allows to "sequence" and "chain" async calls: https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Android

For a more advanced execution control, have a look at RxJava: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava

Also, You can avoid such issues in future be separating functionality from its execution mode. That is, Write the code in simple methods of respective classes, don't make it "Tasks". Create Tasks separately as pure containers of some method calls, that can call any sequence of given functions from background, or foreground.

Answer (score 0):

Actually in the latest Android versions AsyncTask is already running on single thread pool executor. But to not depend on default behavior you can run it on you own Executor. So you can create single thread executor:

```
Executor singleThreadExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

and just run your `AsyncTask`s on it one by one:

```
synchronize (tasksLock) {
    new A().executeOnExecutor(singleThreadExecutor);
    new B().executeOnExecutor(singleThreadExecutor);
    new C().executeOnExecutor(singleThreadExecutor);
}

// on some your event
synchronize (tasksLock) {
    new D().executeOnExecutor(singleThreadExecutor);
    new E().executeOnExecutor(singleThreadExecutor);
    new F().executeOnExecutor(singleThreadExecutor);
}
```

Executor guarantees that they will be started in the order `executeOnExecutor` was called.

Comment: will not work. if B is being executed and D starts, D will execute before C

Comment: It will. I've edited the answer - synchronize added to prevent issues with concurrency.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider that as a queue of tasks. If you start `AsyncTask` normally (call `task.execute()` only) --> every task will be pushed into a queue in a thread off UI thread. Which called first, will be executed first. Therefore, your tasks will be start one by one and which is started first based on which `task.execute()` called first.
 If you want to call 2 sequences of `tasks` in 2 difference `threads`, I suggest that you use [ExecutorService](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

 There some important notes from early version of android OS:

> When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[]) with THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

*put the task A to a variable on executing it.

```
A taskA = new A();
taskA.execute();
```

* And later you have to check whether the  task A is running by

```
if (taskA != null && taskA.getStatus() == A.Status.RUNNING) {
   // Task A still running
   return;
}else{
   // Task A completed 
   new D().execute();
}
```